# Scroll movement not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll, safari

I use below JavaScript for scrolling, but it doesn't work in Safari.

I remove this below code which was working in Safari, but not working smoothly.

[Link is here](http://artfacets.com/Aesthatic_wp/)

```
jQuery(".scrollBg a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
            //  alert(window_width);
            //jQuery('html').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top-38+'px'}, 1000);
            if(window_width<=375){
                jQuery('html').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top+60+'px'}, 1000);
            }
            else if(window_width<=500){
                jQuery('html').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top+60+'px'}, 1000);
            }
            else {
                jQuery('html').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top-38+'px'}, 1000);
            }
    });
```

Please, do you know of a working smooth scroll for Safari?

Comment: Try `$('html,body').animate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

OMG. Don't reinvent the wheel. You should use
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

It works for any browser (safari, chrome, safari mobile, chrome mobile, ffox).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, Safari's scroll animation needs to be enabled under Safari > Develop > Experimental Features > CSSOM View Smooth Scrolling. Most users won't have this option enabled as it is not enabled in Safari by default, however the browser will still move to its intended target. Use this:

```js
window?.scrollTo({ top: ref?.current?.offsetTop - 48, behavior: "smooth" });
```

Where 'ref' is your intended target. All other major browsers support animation out of the box. To see full support go to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollto).